# FileVault 2 gives "boot file not written" error

Tags: encryption, filevault

I'm trying to enable FileVault 2 in Mountain Lion, but a few steps into the process of turning on the encryption I get the error "Boot file not written" and the encryption fails to succeed.

Anyone with similar problem or even better has a solution to the problem?

I've done some googling and the only thing I come up with is some long-shot advice to wipe your entire system, but that's not really what I had in mind.

Suggestions?

Comment: You may be interested in http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72576/26522, where I ran into your very problem after following [one advice](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73163/26522) on how to enable disk encryption. Currently, there is a Bounty on the question, so perhaps even more useful will come out of this.

Comment: For future reference: For me it turned out to be a faulty or arcane driver. Once removed the problem disappeared. Tip: Look in the system logs for hints.